# To export sqlite db schema in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am playing around with sqlite db in android. My question is, how to export schema for the db of a project?

Maybe a class `SchemaExporter` works like: `exporter.export("test.db")`. One would only need to create the object and takes the name of the db of your project as input. Then it will output schema for this entire db, which could be immediately used to create the same db in another sqlite environment.

Note I want to export the **schema**, not the db itself.

Comment: At the risk of causing offence, it sounds like you want to reverse-engineer databases from other peoples' apps. If not then why would you need to do this? Surely if it's your own app then you'll have already created the database and have full knowledge of all of the tables and schema. No?

Comment: Easiest solution: Use your app on an emulator or a device where you have root access. Navigate to your database directory and pull the db file. Open it with an desktop tool of your choice and you have all you need.

Comment: @Squonk i have this c/s model and db at both sides needs to sync. my initial thought is to export the schema of the client side, by which we could create the same db at server side without configuring everything again. I have multiple different apps need this work.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite itself does not have such a function.

The [`sqlite` command-line tool](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) has the `.schema` command. You could run it under Android, or look at its source and copy the logic into your program.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What do you mean by running it under android, executing it in android code? I tried to run .schema in function like `SQLitedatabase.execSQL(".schema")` but not working.